# how to make margin-left auto increment with bootstrap 3.0.0

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, gsap

i need add margin-left into .card class "style" element auto generate margin-left every time post page input.

my jquery version 1.12.4

my idea is

```
if .card css style margin-left 0 and with 479px set position 0
else set position margin-left 479px 
else set position mergin-left ...px
```

becuse im new learning javascript, so im trying help ask question with this code

[enter link description here](https://codepen.io/andreas-toberick/pen/zYReRdv)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found solution.

```
$(function () {
$(".card").css("margin-left", function (i) {
  return i * 479;
});
```

});